# Laravel .htaccess file is adding /public/ to all my links to external websites

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

My Laravel .htaccess file is adding /public/ to all my links to external websites, how can I fix that. I have only this in .htaccess:

RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

Please help me resolve this

Thank you.

Comment: That's not Laravel's `.htaccess` file. See https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess. Your fundamental problem is you need to set your server's `DocumentRoot` to point to the `public` folder of your app.

Answer (score 1):

try this on your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "^\.env">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
 </FilesMatch>

Options All -Indexes

<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Content-Disposition "attachment"
# for older browsers
Header set Content-Type "application/octet-stream"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: Thanks I will try. Do I need all of that or is there a lighter version for my issue?

Comment: try using all that. replace your .htaccess file with it

Comment: I've paste it to public/.htaccess - my external links still have "/public/", and this is my root .htaccess:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: nope, but I've deleted it from domain because I have to fix this first...